# Unity error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityStandardAssets' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Even though there are surely a bunch of the same questions out there revealing the same exact topic as my problem, but I haven't found a suitable answer for me, therefore I do still have an issue.

**Problem**

I'm trying to code a game in Unity. The version I'm using is `Unity 2021.3.15f1`.

There, I have made a script (C#), which objective is to show a sequence message above the screen (subtitles for short). However, while making the script, I experienced the following error:

`Assets\Scripts\Sequences\AOpening.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityStandardAssets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here's my `AOpening` code, where the error came from:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AOpening : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject FadeScreenIn;
    public GameObject TextBox;

    void Start () {
        ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController> ().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine (ScenePlayer ());
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayer () {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.5f);
        FadeScreenIn.SetActive (false);
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "I need to get out of here.";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
        ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonController> ().enabled = true;

    }

}
```

**What I tried?**

- Relaunching the Unity engine
- Removing `using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;` from the script

None of these helped me.

I'd be more than grateful if someone here would be able to help me resolve this problem. Many thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Did you install the unity standard assets?

Comment: @BugFinder seems like not. I can't see it either in the directory or in the project itself. Is there a way to download it? I searched it up in Asset Store but found nothing

Comment: Last time I looked it was distinctly out of date and i havent looked in a year.   But the unity first person is in the store. So use that